# What mass does an evaporating black hole have when it's schwarzschild radius equals the Planck length?

Tags: black-hole, mass, hawking-radiation

I am referring to Hawking radiation and the decrease in mass of the black hole with time

Comment: 1/2 Planck mass. See https://www.vttoth.com/CMS/physics-notes/311-hawking-radiation-calculator

Comment: The physicallity of such an object is doubtful, it would exist in the realm of quantum gravity, and we don't have a working model of quantum gravity yet.

Answer (score 6):

A black hole's Schwarzschild radius is $$R=\frac{2GM}{c^2}$$

In Planck units, $G=1$ and $c=1$, so the above reduces to $R=2M$ with mass and radius expressed in Planck units. Thus a black hole with a mass of one half Planck masses will have a Schwarzschild radius of one Planck length.

Comment: Thanks  .Useful equation.